# POST to REST API from webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, post

I am trying to post a JSON data struct to a REST API service from a webpage from. On submitting the form, javascript will capture form field values, make JSON data, then POST the data to my REST API.  I am not entirely sure how to do this with JavaScript. Can anyone point me in the right direction or drop some sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery, it's got some nice helpers for this kind of stuff.

Check out the [jQuery.post documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post), you probably want the `postJSON` method.

As for getting started with jQuery, check out their [getting started page](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

You can get a form's data with

`var data = $('#formid').serializeArray();`

Then you can use that in the postJSON method:

```
$.post(url, data, callback, "json");
```

Comment: Could I do this without jQuery?

Comment: @jomille You can use plain javascript to the same effect, however it's more tedious than using jQuery. [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Ok, I can use jQuery.  Now a larger issue (I might need to create another thread). I need to POST to a different domain than my webpage will be on.  Can I do this?

Comment: Due to Cross-site Scripting security concerns ([Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), browsers don't let you easily do this kind of thing easily. However, it is possible. You'll want to take a look at JSONP. I've found a [tutorial here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/).

Answer (score 1):

Or for even easier solution, use my jQuery plugin: https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest

> I need to POST to a different domain than my webpage will be on. Can I do this?

If you don't care about older IE's you can use headers to allow cross domain requests: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS